# Check integration of google analytics IP anonymization

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, ip

How I can check that IP anonymization is working or not on my website.

Because, when I am opening inspect element, then Network, opening any page and click on some of the responses, in Headers, I cannot find "aip" parameter that is responsible for the IP address as I read in so many tutorials over the internet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find "aip" parameter through the Inspector (i.e. in Google Chrome) in Network tab (and in its Header tab) for the 'collect' call of Google Analytics.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's okay.

My problem was that after implementation, also in view page source I was not been able to find the code.

But, the problem was in the module for the Google Analytics.
After Activation-Deactivation of it, everything was working fine.

Thanks again!